# Macbook Air connected to Dell 24W2408 Monitor via DVI-D suddenly turns to static

Tags: dvi

I'm trying to figure out if this is a hardware or software issue. What happens is that I'm using the monitor and it will suddenly go to all static. This happens a few times a day and seems to be increasing in frequency. I used this monitor with this computer for about 2 years with no issues.

To fix it, I have to either turn the monitor off and on. Or unplug the DVI-D cable and plug it back in.

Comment: Interesting I have been having this issue with my MacMini connected to my TV whenever I switch back to the Mini from another source. And I have used the same "fix" by unplugging and reconnecting the HDMI cable. Can you connect your monitor with another interface e.g. DVI adapter or Thunderbolt?

Comment: @ArchonOSX - turns out I was connected to DVI, not HDMI like I thought. However, luckily, my monitor has 2 DVI inputs and I switched to the other input and I have not had the problem. So seems to be an issue with the monitor/input.